# Get embeded page with javascript for myBB

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and I am woundering how to change it so that it will get the information without you having to use the click function.

[Image from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0L5D.png)

```
            if (PREVIEW == 1) {
                $(this).before('<span class="prev-img" alt="Preview" title="Preview">&#128269;</span>');
                var linkurl = $(this).attr('href');
                $(this).prev('.prev-img').on('click', function() {
                    $('.am_preview').each(function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('am_preview');
                    });
                    $(this).next('a').addClass('am_preview');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: "xmlhttp.php?action=load_preview&linkurl="+encodeURI(linkurl),
                        async: true,
                        success: function(response) {
                            $('.am_preview').outerHTML(response.html);
                            $(".am_embed").css("max-width", MAXWIDTH+"px");
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            $('.am_errorMessage').each(function () {
                                $(this).hide();
                            });
                            $('.am_preview').after('<div class="am_errorMessage">' + NOPREVIEW + '</div>');
                        }
                    });
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('.am_errorMessage').each(function () {
                            $(this).fadeOut('fast');
                        });
                    }, 6000);
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            }
            // Embed from sites with oembed api
            if (file.indexOf('soundcloud.com/') !== -1) {
                $(this).scembed();
                $(this).prev('.prev-img').hide();
            }
```

Comment: Provide the code here, because it is a hassle for everyone to just give a solution with an image.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am new here so it is great to get all the info I can get on how to do things right,

Comment: What do you mean by "get the information"? Why not remove the `click` handlers?

Comment: I can just remove the click handlers?
How would that look?

I do not know anything about Javascript and am trying to learn as I go.

Comment: I will try to explain more.

If you look at this page http://ateisme.no/showthread.php?tid=5 you will see a magnifier glass that you have to click on to preview the article.

What I am trying to do is have the article load with out having to click the magnifier glass.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What keeps you from using the same logic from that `click` handlers in any other event?